# Indexing sequence steps for open source Lucene, working with SQL or Nosql

Tags: c#, lucene.net, architecture

I am new in the game for open source.
had a question, before i dive into what i plan to do. Assuming I plan to use c# , with no NoSQL (not planned which one (RavenDb, or MongoDb)), I wanted to do indexing for a site in asp.net.

I would like to use Lucene.net for indexing data and page links on my site, When do you actually tell Lucene.Net to start indexing?

I mean, is it a background process that starts indexing every night, just like the SharePoint indexes or the moment you call insert to nosql at the time you should call to index a record.

How about links on pages, when should the crawl engine run. I guess I am thinking in terms of SharePoint world and needs to be corrected by some people on this board.

I am particularly interested in sequence of steps, I am sorry, i am failing to understand when and why.
Any explanation or links to examples would help.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Sweety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene is a search engine, not a crawler. So you would need to find a crawler which inserts the data into the Lucene index.

Think of Lucene as a SQL server. It can store data and retrieve data based on queries. But you have to create the application which actually inserts and queries the data.

You could very well use Solr (built on top of Lucene) and Nutch, both java projects, and use web services to between your C# app and the search index. The java version of Lucene is also under constant development, while the .Net version is somewhat up in the air.

Comment: Thanks, But using wewbservice becomes a single thread often time, isn;t that right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Using Webserice becomes a single thread framework, 
How about the sequence the indexes should be built overnight and the Crawler you mentioned SOLR , is it always alive . Sorry need a bit more detail information.

Comment: Solr is a framework which uses Nutch (the crawler). You would then need to incorporate a scheduler. Take a look at http://www.constellio.com/ for a Solr/Lucene distribution with a crawler and a scheduler. Full admin UI. That said, you could also use Search Server Express - http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx